# I tried to build a theme from scratch and it crashed everything

Tags: errors

> Notice: Constant WP_CRON_LOCK_TIMEOUT already defined in /home3/premivu6/public_html/wp-config.php on line 91

> Notice: Constant AUTOSAVE_INTERVAL already defined in /home3/premivu6/public_html/wp-config.php on line 92

> Notice: Constant WP_POST_REVISIONS already defined in /home3/premivu6/public_html/wp-config.php on line 93

> Notice: Constant EMPTY_TRASH_DAYS already defined in /home3/premivu6/public_html/wp-config.php on line 94

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home3/premivu6/public_html/wp-config.php:91) in /home3/premivu6/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 6270

not sure how to fix

Answer (score 1):

Hard to tell, since you didn't share your code.  But the  error message tells you why.

But if you are trying to DEFINE previously defined constants (which is what those are, since they were defined in wp-config.php - look at that file in the indicated line number), then that would be the cause of your errors.

**"Constants" are 'constant'.** Never-changing. Once defined, that's it. Don't try to change the value of a constant that has been DEFINEd.